# Why does varuintN has a fixed bit number “N” even if it uses LEB28 encoding in wasm binary format?

Tags: webassembly

LEB128 is a "variable-length integer", which means that we can save space if we have a number that has many zeroes inside. like an example below:

For a particular number **12**:

uint32: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001100

leb128: 00001100

varuint32(leb128 with paddings): 10000000 10000000 10000000 00001100 (0x80 0x80 0x80 0x0b)

quoted from the official website:

> A LEB128 variable-length integer, limited to N bits (i.e., the values [0, 2^N-1]), represented by at most ceil(N/7) bytes that may contain padding 0x80 bytes.

Did I misunderstand anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integer encoding in WebAssembly binaries is still variable-length, it just imposes a maximum length. See also the [draft spec](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/binary/values.html#integers) for clarifying examples. The reason for this restriction is that it allows decoders to be optimised by completely unrolling the decoding loop, which can make quite a difference.